# find the smallest e1-e2 in a set of many elements in Java language

Tags: java, algorithm

I have a problem that is: given a set of integers (e1,e2,e3....) , determine the smallest ex-ey (the smallest result of the subtraction of any 2 elements in the set). I know this has to do with algorithm but I now have no knowledge about that. You can help me by giving the logics or code in Java. Many thanks!

Comment: are negative results allowed? If yes, it is simply smallest integer - biggest integer.

Comment: @LuigiEdlCarno I suspect he wants to know the smallest _absolute_ difference

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The most optimal solution I can think of is to sort the set ( `O(n log n)` ) and then perform pairwise comparison on each consecutive pair in the set ( `O(n)` ).

The "naive" algorithm which compares every element against every other element would be `O(n^2)`.

Comment: Very true!! This is what even I thought at first read (+1)

Answer (score -1):

```
public class HelloWorld{

     public static void main(String []args){
        //System.out.println("Hello World");

        int[] array = {10, 21, 323, 24, 45, 26, 47, 58, 69};

        int[] resultPair = {10, 21}; //lets assume

        for(int i=0; i<array.length; i++)
        {
            int minuend = array[i];

            for(int j=0; j<array.length; j++)
            {
                int subtrahend = array[j];

                int res = minuend - subtrahend;
                if(res >= 0 && res < (resultPair[0] - resultPair[1]))
                {
                    resultPair[0] = minuend;
                    resultPair[1] = subtrahend;

                }  

            }
        }
        System.out.println();

        // reverse check
        for(int i=array.length-1; i>=0; i--)
        {
            int minuend = array[i];

            for(int j=0; j<array.length; j++)
            {
                int subtrahend = array[j];

                int res = minuend - subtrahend;
                if(res >= 0 && res < (resultPair[0] - resultPair[1]))
                {
                    resultPair[0] = minuend;
                    resultPair[1] = subtrahend;

                }  

            }
        }

        System.out.println(resultPair[0]);
        System.out.println(resultPair[1]);
        }


}
```